Scroller extension with `fillContainer = TRUE` in DT/Shiny
Is it possible to use the Scroller extension for DataTables and use the fillContainer option with DT and Shiny?
Below is a minimal example of what I am trying to accomplish. The table loads as expected, but if you scroll it gets reduced down to only 9 rows and no longer fills the container.
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(
    style = "height: 500px",
    DT::DTOutput("table", height = "100%")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- DT::renderDT({
    DT::datatable(
      iris,
      options = list(
        scrollY = 200,
        scroller = TRUE,
        deferRender = TRUE
      ),
      fillContainer = TRUE,
      extensions = "Scroller",
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


I'm not sure if there is a bug with using fillContainer = TRUE and the Scroller extension, but I have found a resolution to the issue using the scrollResize plugin for DataTables.
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(
    style = "height: 500px",
    DT::DTOutput("table", height = "100%")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- DT::renderDT({
    DT::datatable(
      iris,
      options = list(
        scrollY = 200,
        scroller = TRUE,
        deferRender = TRUE,
        scrollResize = TRUE
      ),
      extensions = "Scroller",
      plugins = "scrollResize"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)



One caveat I should add is that the paging information will be wrong using this method. But you can correct the issue using the DataTable API (e.g. $('#table').find('table').DataTable().scroller.measure())
